# Italic not shown in off-topic reasons on closed/on-hold banner on mobile

Tags: bug, mobile-web, close-reasons, fonts

I saw a question on Electrical Engineering closed on my laptop:

> [image]

Later I switched to my Android phone and checked the same question on the browser:

> [image]

Hmmm, the italic on words *use* and *design* is gone.

Side note: [The question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/351755/176201) I discovered this bug on <s>may be deleted soon</s> is deleted already, but a CM or developer should be able to check it. For other people, poke around EE and you'll find other closed questions suitable for verifying this issue. Alternatively, you can check the flag dialog as long as you have 15 rep (or the assoc bonus).